# Any other way of saying "be related to"?

Tags: synonyms

I want to know more ways of saying "be related to".
I can come up with "be relevant to","have relevance with","have connection with".

**Added Later:**
It is suggested I should clarify the context.
I have asked a question on stackoverflow. In the question I wrote "I find it is relevant to Physics2D.SyncTransforms()".
[My question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68801079/unity-rigidbody-moveposition-is-not-working-if-transform-position-is-just-cha/74247578#74247578)

Comment: We need to know the context. Without it our suggestions will not be helpful. "Be related to" and "be relevant to" have different meanings. I am related to, but not relevant to, my sister. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Not giving enough detail in your question is intrinsically linked to getting questions closed down.

Comment: It's not remotely idiomatic to say *X has relevance **with** Y*, and even after including the (mandatory) article in *X has **a** connection **with** Y*, that one's still *very* uncommon compared to *X has a connection **to** Y*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context suggests "to concern" might be suitable, eg "this summary [concerns/relates to]  your recent activity"

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe say - "to be linked to".

> I find this concept being linked to The Big Bang.